# angular-material-components/datetime-picker rendering issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

material-components/datetime-picker@8.0.0 with angular 14, sometimes though the calendar popup renders out of place(see image below). I thought it's a cache problem and indeed with a hard reload was gone but after it came back.I have added `outputHashing:'all'` and `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">` in order to solve the cache problem, but it didn't helped. Also this happens in the 10% of the cases, otherwise the calendar is rendered properly, any suggestions how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following classes in your css:

```
button.mat-calendar-body-cell {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

td.mat-calendar-body-cell {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}
```

Here are some useful links to your issue:

https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/295

https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/269